# Can't put class name from var into addClass command

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to build my own 360' jQuery auto gallery. I can add class, however, if I go back to box1 with slider, it doesn't add new class. Thanks for help.

Here is the project put to jsfiddle:

**http://jsfiddle.net/Z8knE/19/**

```
var interval;
    interval = setInterval(function () {
        var chosenvalue = $(".amount1").val()
        var chosenclass = "box" + chosenvalue
        $(".box1").addClass(chosenclass,1000);
}, 100);
```

Comment: What's removeClassaddClass??

Comment: @Archer sorry just typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the quotes from around the word *chosenclass* in your `addClass()` method:

```
var interval;
    interval = setInterval(function () {
        var chosenvalue = $(".amount1").val()
        var chosenclass = "box" + chosenvalue
        $(".box1").addClass(chosenclass);
}, 100);
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z8knE/26/)

Comment: but now the problem is the car doesn't roll back :(

Comment: try removing all classes at the beginning of your function. Then it will add the appropriate one at the end.

Comment: What's the 2nd parameter of `addClass` for?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `chosenclass` instead of `'chosenclass'`, you don't need to pass secound parameter.

```
$(".box1").addClass(chosenclass);
```

If you want to remove all class then use `.removeClass()` otherwise pass className to remove

See Docs for [addClass](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) and [removeClass](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/)

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Z8knE/25/)

Comment: if you're using jQuery `addClass()` - you have too many arguments

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple problems in the code you are tryng to write.

1. Way of using removeClass and addClass.
2. You dont need interval for monitoring change of value. You can use change event of slider for same.
3. You need to remove previous classes added so that backward animation works.

I have rewritten the code to suit your requirements. Note that jquery doesnt have method for removing class by wildcards. So used function as argument in removeClass which uses reg ex magic to do the stuff.

```
$(function() {
    $( "#slider1" ).slider({
        range: "min",
        value: 1,
        min: 1,
        max: 9,
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( ".amount1" ).val( ui.value);

            var chosenvalue = $(".amount1").val()
            var chosenclass = "box" + chosenvalue

            $(".mycar").removeClass (function (index, css) {
                return (css.match (/box\d+/g) || []).join(' ');
            });
            $(".mycar").addClass(chosenclass);
        }
    });
    $( ".amount1" ).val($( "#slider1" ).slider( "value" ));
});
```

Find updated fiddle here.

http://jsfiddle.net/Z8knE/37/